# How to decode the hash function?

Tags: solidity, remix

bytes32 constant myHash = sha256("test");
 getting hash value like 
 (0x4135aa9dc1b842a653dea846903ddb95bfb8c5a10c504a7fa16e10bc31d1fdf0)
 There is any function for decode it? or how to decode it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sha256 is a one-way hashing algorithm. You can't (efficiently) derive the source from the hash.

One-way hashing algorithms are (among many many other things) used to verify someone has data, without actually having to know the contents of that data. An example of such data could be a password. A server stores hashes of passwords, of which the actual passwords cannot be derived. That means, if the hashes are stolen, the thief still needs to guess what the actual password is. When a user logs in, they send their password to the server, which hashes it. That hash is then compared to the hash that is stored in the database. If they're the same, the user can log in.

Comment: then what is the use of one way hash in solidity will you please explain me with example?